# Have the producers of The Walking Dead acknowledged that the logo is supposed to be decaying?

Tags: tv, the-walking-dead, behind-the-scenes, robert-kirkman

This picture has been floating around the interwebs, along with claims that the idea was to create a sense of increasing decay in the show's logo:

[image]

[image]
Season 6

However, the logo seems to have become **more** intact in season 2 than it was in season 1, and at any rate, the supposed "decay" is uneven and inconsistent - portions of the text that were damaged in one season are apparently repaired in subsequent seasons (e.g., the final "D" in seasons 5-6).

### Have any of the *show's* creators, producers, etc, commented on/confirmed the decay idea, or is this just a fan theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer seems to be...

## No.

There does not seem to be *any* official comment on the decaying title card by the producers.

I went through the [AMC web site](http://www.amc.com/shows/the-walking-dead) with a fine-tooth comb (not just the sections on *The Walking Dead*, on the off-chance that there was some post or comment somewhere on the site regarding the title card), the [official Walking Dead Twitter account](http://twitter.com/WalkingDead_AMC), producer [Gale Anne Hurd's Twitter account](http://twitter.com/GunnerGale), as well as various press releases.

At this point in time, the only statement on the matter that has any slight air of authority is the aforementioned blurb on the [Skybound Comics web site](http://www.thewalkingdead.com/evolution-of-the-twd-show-logo/).  The statement on that web site does not cite anyone involved in the production of the television series and seems to be just a reiteration of what we *think* is happening to the title card.

So, at the present time, the decaying-logo theory seems to be **just a fan theory.**

Comment: I also sent a message to their official Twitter, asking this very question, and I've received no response.

Answer (score 8):

The photo actually originates from [Skybound Comics](http://www.thewalkingdead.com/evolution-of-the-twd-show-logo/) official website:

> Did you know that AMC’s been subtly changing the Walking Dead logo on
>   the title screen of the opening credits? It’s been decaying since the
>   first season to reflect the decay of the world in the show (hm, does
>   that make this a de-evolution of a logo?). Pretty cool! By season 20
>   it will be completely unreadable! Just kidding. We captured the title
>   screens and put this GIF together for you to check out

[image]

http://comicbook.com/2015/05/16/the-walking-dead-tv-show-logo-has-been-decaying/

Comment: Can you explain what relation the comic book publisher has to AMC and the show, besides each being licensed to produce one format of the franchise?

Comment: @WadCheber That goes outside the bounds of the question.

Comment: @Axelrod - I'm trying to determine how this answers the question, if at all.  I asked about the *show's* producers, and this answer only addresses the *comic book's* publisher.

Comment: @Axelrod - And I'm actually the one who found the quote Richard edited in.  It strikes me as an unofficial fan project rather than a statement of inside info.  As such, it is absolutely within the scope of the question - i.e., I asked "What about the show?" and the answer was "Here's something about the comics".